# iOS: Upload multiple files using Dropbox

Tags: ios, ios7, dropbox, dropbox-api

All that I have researched integrating Dropbox iOS SDK requires logging in to authenticate/authenticate a user.

But this is what I want to accomplish

1. Use only one user account. (Without authorization)
2. Create a random public folder(in same account) and upload files to that folder.
3. Get the folder link.

It's basically sending generated files from the app to an account.

How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. However, it is technically possible to connect to just one account. The SDKs don't offer explicit support for it and we don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons.

For example, any user who extracts the access token from your app will be able to read every file in the Dropbox account, delete everything, replace it, etc.

However if you did want to go this route, instead of kicking off the authorization flow, you would manually use an existing access token for your app. (Just be careful not to revoke it, e.g. via https://www.dropbox.com/account/applications.)

Comment: By authenticating via an app. Or you can use my app: https://dbxoauth2.site44.com, which will just spit out the token for you (after you authenticate).

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm lost. I generated the key already, but how do I "authenticate via the app"? Is this the way to do it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484389/using-saved-dropbox-authentication-details-on-android ?

Comment: You can follow any of the tutorials on dropbox.com/developers. They pretty much all start with how to do authentication.